# When using KaTeX, why put one <script> in the head and one after the body?

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, katex

See [this example of the use of KaTeX on a Jekyll website](https://github.com/cben/sandbox/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/katex.html).

1. Why is the KaTeX script in the head but the inline script that does the KaTeX rendering after the body?
2. If I am using KaTeX on my Github pages website, would it be better to put both scripts in the head with `async` or `defer` attributes as described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already referred to: [placing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

1) Placing one script tag in header means the `stop everything before this script is loaded` So, in your [KaTeX example](https://github.com/cben/sandbox/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/katex.html) The author wants to emphasize in order for the example to work, `katex.min` file should be loaded and parsed first, until then, he doesn't want to load/parse any of the `html` content because, the the second `<script>` in body will fail if the `katex.min` isn't loaded properly.

This is just one way of doing it. Bu there are many more like:

> Remove the `<script>` tag from head and place before the `<script>` in body
>
> Remove the `<script>` tag after the body and place it after the `<script>` tag in head with `defer` attribute in both the scripts (so, we need not wait for them to be downloaded and go to body part to print things, and once they are loaded execute them) defer will make sure that everything in the `dom` is loaded asynchronously except that the scripts will be loaded in the order which they are declared.